# How to retrieve custom UserDetails from SecurityContextHolder in jHipster?

Tags: java, spring-security, jhipster

I'm new to jHipster, and I'm trying to associate users to a company id in order to limit the entities they have access to based on the said company id.

I'd like to be able to use the SecurityContext to store my custom implementation of UserDetails. 
I've followed multiple tutorials to the letter and can't seem to get it working: the returned object by SecurityContext is always of type org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User and therefore cannot cast it into into my implemented UserDetails class.

**DomainUserDetailsService.java**

```java
@Service("domainUserDetailsService")
public class DomainUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DomainUserDetailsService.class);

    private  UserRepository userRepository;

    public DomainUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {
        log.debug("Authenticating {}", login);

        User user = userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByEmail(login).get();

        return new UserDetails(user, 22L);
    }
```

**UserDetails.java**

```java
public class UserDetails implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails {
    private User user;
    private Long companyId = 0L;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Long getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(Long companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    public UserDetails(User user, Long companyId) {
        this.user = user;
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user.getAuthorities().stream().map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName().toString())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return user.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getLogin();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public User getUserDetails() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;

    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder, @Qualifier("domainUserDetailsService") UserDetailsService userDetailsService, TokenProvider tokenProvider, CorsFilter corsFilter, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport) {
        this.authenticationManagerBuilder = authenticationManagerBuilder;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
    }


    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

 @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
......
```

**SecurityUtils.java**

```java
public static UserDetails getCurrentUserDetail() {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null) {
            if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
                UserDetails springSecurityUser = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
                return springSecurityUser;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is that in SecurityUtils, authentication.getPrincipal().getClass() always is of type class **org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User**.
I'd expect it to be of type **UserDetails**.

**EDIT**
The code does go through DomainUserDetailsService, as I can see it in the logs.

I believe the problem is related to the Authentication being overridden in [TokenProvider.java](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-gateway/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/security/jwt/TokenProvider.java) during **createToken** which is called during user authentication in [UserJWTController.java](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/registry/web/rest/UserJWTController.java)

Comment: `log.debug("Authenticating {}", login);` Can you find this log  when do authentication ? and Can you  share your HttpSecurity?

Comment: What's tokenProvider ?

Comment: @chaoluo, yes the codes does go through log.debug("Authenticating {}", login);
TokenProvider is a class generated by jHipster. Here's an [example of it](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-gateway/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/security/jwt/TokenProvider.java). Going through it, I think I might have found my issue inside of 
`public Authentication getAuthentication(String token)
`

Comment: Can you share your HttpSecurtiy?

Comment: have you tried using a middle table? something like `Employee` with `company_id` and `user_id` as fields? It worked for me and spared my of many troubles

Answer (score 0):

you should override the `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`, not `@Autowired public void configureGlobal`

```
 @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, and it doesn't seem to make a difference. Even based on the code before, it would still go through DomainUserDetailsService as I can see it in the logs. @chalou above asked about TokenProvider class, and it I believe I found the problem, yet I don't know how to properly solve it yet.... The problem seems to be in the method  public Authentication getAuthentication(String token)  of the class [TokenProvider](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-gateway/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/security/jwt/TokenProvider.java)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue and I handled it by making a few updates in TokenProvider.createToken and TokenProvider.getAuthentication methods. Idea is to save tenant (company in your case) ID or any other variables in JWT Token in *createToken* method and then extract them in *getAuthentication* method. Below is code of my methods:

```
public String createToken(Authentication authentication, boolean rememberMe, String channel) {
        String authorities = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        long now = (new Date()).getTime();
        Date validity;
        if (rememberMe) {
            validity = new Date(now + this.tokenValidityInMillisecondsForRememberMe);
        } else {
            validity = new Date(now + this.tokenValidityInMilliseconds);
        }

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Long userPkId = null;
        Long tenantId = null;

        if (auth != null) {
            Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();

            if (principal instanceof DomainUserDetails) {
                DomainUserDetails domainUserDetails = (DomainUserDetails) principal;
                tenantId = domainUserDetails.getTenantId();
                userPkId = domainUserDetails.getId();
            }
        }

        return Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(authentication.getName())
            .claim(AUTHORITIES_KEY, authorities)
            .claim(USER_ID_KEY, userPkId)
            .claim(TENANT_KEY, tenantId)
            .claim(CHANNEL_KEY, channel)
            .signWith(key, SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
            .setExpiration(validity)
            .compact();
    }
```

Now we can get these variables from JWT token

```
public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(key)
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities =
            Arrays.stream(claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString().split(","))
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Integer userPkId = (Integer) claims.get(USER_ID_KEY);
        Integer tenandId = (Integer)  claims.get(TENANT_KEY);
        String channel = (String) claims.get(CHANNEL_KEY);

        DomainUserDetails principal = new DomainUserDetails(claims.getSubject(), "", authorities, userPkId, tenandId, channel);

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, token, authorities);
    }
```